# Ionic Framework week selection plugin. I want to be able to select a week from a calendar control

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Something similar to this, but for Ionic v1 or v2

http://www.scripts.morshed-alam.com/week-picker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up using

```
<ion-input id="exampleInput" type="week" name="input" placeholder="YYYY-W##" min="2012-W32"></ion-input>
```